# Save as, winforms (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, save-as

I wrote this code for a "save" button

```
        {
            File.WriteAllText(ofd.FileName, textBox1.Text);
        }
```

And I want to do a "save as" button, to create a file by my app but idk how to do it, someone know how to ? Or just give me a doc, thx.

Comment: How does this code save anything?? It seems to read **from** a file, not save **to** it

Comment: woops, wrong code ! I'll edit it

Comment: Use the SaveFileDialog. Once the user browsed the place of the new file it can be obtained by saveFileDialog.FileName. Put this value to the File.WriteAllText method.

Comment: Take a look at [SaveFileDialog In C# (C# Corner)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/savefiledialog-in-C-Sharp/). I hope this can help you to enjoy C# coding: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm)

Comment: thx ! I'm new here, why there is "-2" to my post ?

Comment: @kichi Because your question shows very little research effort which is one of the reasons to downvote (if you hover over the downvote button it will show a tooltip). A quick google search for "winforms save as" pulls up the duplicate question I link below

Comment: And also probably because you said "give me a doc", but people here resent being seen as a free do-my-research service. And also because, as I pointed out, the question initially did not make sense. And not everyone sticks around to see if you updated it or not. It's a good idea to proof read your question carefully before you post it, as most  voting and commenting tends to happen in the first few minutes

Comment: oh, I see. Thx ! I'll be carefuly next time !

Answer (score 0):

To prompt the user with a "Save As" file prompt:

Create a button on your form.  Set the Click event to btnSaveAsClick().

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void btnSaveAs_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = GetSaveFileName("usage.csv");
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) return;
        //Write your file here using 'path'
    }

    private String GetSaveFileName(String SuggestedFileName)
    {
        SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog();
        ofd.FileName = SuggestedFileName;
        ofd.DefaultExt = "csv";
        ofd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        return ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK ? ofd.FileName : "";
    }
}
```

Please remember to click the green checkmark if this solves your issue.

Comment: It's not create the document on my desktop, why ?

Comment: @kichi You'll have to show your code for us to help further

Comment: OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ofd.Filter = "Text | *.txt";
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(ofd.FileName, textBox1.Text);
        }

Comment: Instead of textBox1.Text, use a const string e.g. "Testing" to verify that File.WriteAllText() is working.

Comment: @kichi: The SaveFileDialog DOES NOT SAVE anything. It returns you Ok, if the user selected a file, and you can optain the filename from the instance of the object - as you see in the "GetSaveFileName" method in the last line.